# Repairing/patching concrete foundation of house

Tags: concrete, foundation

What's the best (or maybe easiest and most affordable would be more accurate) route to patch the concrete of our house foundation? It's kind of crumbling in places and needs a facelift. Ideas/options?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this a structural fix or a cosmetic one? Is there any cracking or other signs of structural failure on the inside, or is this limited to surface deterioration on the outside?

Comment: Just surface deterioration.. No cracks or structural problems. Cosmetic.